# python dataframe parsing using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as a sample below which is imported from csv. I'd like to extract first 6 letters as mentioned in the output and would like output as dataframe format only.

Tab delimited Input:

```
123456789_abcd_dd 3456434534_abelom_ad 123987323_tyewer_qwer 562329872_zcxvzcv_mnbcc
345345345_abcd_dd 6834512342_llllom_ad 368887323_jnbcer_qwer 123429872_iuytzcv_mnbcc
```

Tab delimited Expected output:

```
123456 345643 123987 562329
345345 683451 368887 123429
```

I have many such rows and columns hence need help with solution that iterates over all rows and columns of this dataframe.

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried anything, done any research? You haven't even provided a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the code below

```
df = [['123456789_abcd_dd', '3456434534_abelom_ad', '123987323_tyewer_qwer', '562329872_zcxvzcv_mnbcc'], ['345345345_abcd_dd', '6834512342_llllom_ad', '368887323_jnbcer_qwer', '123429872_iuytzcv_mnbcc']]
df = pd.DataFrame(df).astype('str')
df
output>>> 

                   0                     1                      2 
0  123456789_abcd_dd  3456434534_abelom_ad  123987323_tyewer_qwer   
1  345345345_abcd_dd  6834512342_llllom_ad  368887323_jnbcer_qwer   

df.applymap(lambda x: x[:6])
df

o/p>>>

        0       1       2       3
0  123456  345643  123987  562329
1  345345  683451  368887  123429
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the exact same transformation for all values, you can use `applymap`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['123456789_abcd_dd', '345345345_abcd_dd'], 'B': ['3456434534_abelom_ad', '6834512342_llllom_ad'],
                   'C': ['123987323_tyewer_qwer', '368887323_jnbcer_qwer'], 'D': ['562329872_zcxvzcv_mnbcc', '123429872_iuytzcv_mnbcc']})

df.applymap(lambda x: x[:6])

         A       B       C       D
0   123456  345643  123987  562329
1   345345  683451  368887  123429
```